# Open CV VideoCapture Read Method

Tags: java

I'm using an application called Android Studio to write all my code in. I wrote this code:

```
Mat fieldImage = new Mat();
videoCapture.read(fieldImage);
```

But the read method of videocapture objects returns a boolean. So (if I'm correct), that code should raise an error. However, Android Studio did not raise an error. Will this code raise an error or not? And if it does, will this code work in place of it?

```
Mat fieldImage = new Mat();
boolean finishedCapturing =  videoCapture.read(fieldImage);
while(!finishedCapturing) {
finishedCapturing =  videoCapture.read(fieldImage);
}
```

Comment: You are not correct that functions that return booleans "raise an error".  The boolean can indicate success or not, but an exception does not need to be raised.  An exception *can* occur independent of success and requires a `try`/`catch` structure to handle.  The code you wrote will retry the read if it returns false.  It is not recommended to use a while loop like that as it will endlessly retry with as much CPU as the `read` will take.  If it fails once it will likely fail again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of, if any method has a return value, it is not neccessary by you to take this value. Any IDE will normally not give you an error, if you don't take a return value. But if a method is giving you a return value, you should take it and process it as intendend by the method.

For your case, the [Javadoc for VideoCapture](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/javadoc/org/opencv/videoio/VideoCapture.html#read(org.opencv.core.Mat)) states that the return value indicates if the frame could be grabbed.

So in your case you could do something like this

```
Mat fieldImage = new Mat();
boolean hasReadFrame = true;
// Have a do-while loop to only have once the read call
do {
    // Check if a frame has read
    hasReadFrame =  videoCapture.read(fieldImage);
    // after reading, you could do some more logic with the fieldImage
} while (hasReadFrame);
```

Of course, you need to add error / exception handling when needed.

Comment: Thanks! I was a bit confused since it threw an error when I put true all on a line by itself!